# How can I override the create method of a record created from another model in Odoo?

Tags: database, odoo-12

Basically I have a model for hospital appointments, inside that model I have a many-to-one field to another model for patients. What I want is to make that every time I use the "Create and Edit" option in my appointments model to create a record in the patient model this record gets automatically set with state equal to validated (contrary to draft, that is originally set as default), but when I create a patient record from the patient model it saves the record normally, with draft as default

Comment: Odoo is python based, you can use inheritance then override the create function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use context in xml with field definition for example:

```
<field name="partner_id" widget="res_partner_many2one" context="{'search_default_supplier':1, 'default_supplier':1, 'default_customer':0, 'show_vat': True}" domain="[('supplier','=',True)]"  placeholder="Name, TIN, Email, or Reference" />
```

Hope this'll help.

Comment: I'm new to odoo so I don't understand quite well, this would automatically set the state as validated in the patient record I created from the appointment model? Or I still have to override the create() method somewhere else? Thanks!

Comment: There's no need of overriding creating method, you simply have to pass context in field definition (in xml), by context you can set the default value, for more reference you can check purchase_view.xml in purchase module of odoo .